# How do I open/run bluej?

Tags: 12.04

I'm new to Ubuntu. I've previously used bluej on my Windows computer, but now wish to do so on Ubuntu.
I've downloaded bluej and now have a folder on my desktop called `bluej-311`.
When I type 'sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk' in the terminal window, I get the following message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
openjdk-7-jdk is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

How do I run bluej? What do I need to do to proceed from here?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this means that you already have the jdk application

to open the just press the super button then type the name (bluej) of the application

if you need the bluej the link to download is [here](http://www.bluej.org/versions.html). Download the `.deb` package and just try to open it using the software center and get it installed.

Comment: Thank you :) All I needed to do was right click the .deb file and select 'Open with Ubuntu Software Center'.

Comment: @undeze If this answer helped you, please be sure to mark it as correct and maybe even give it an upvote.